# Pyspark - cast a string to integer with trailing zero return Null

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using `Pyspark v3` when `casting` the **reference** column it gives back `null` !

```
+-----------------+
|    reference    |
+-----------------+
|     012345      |
+-----------------+
```

Is this a correct behavior or it should be a pyspark issue ? How can we manage the trailing `0`s in this case ?

```
df.select(f.col('reference').cast('integer'))
+-----------------+
|    reference    |
+-----------------+
|      null       |
+-----------------+
```

Comment: `spark.createDataFrame([("012345",)], ["reference"]).select(F.col('reference').cast('int')).show()` returns 12345 value as expected. How did you get null?

Comment: @blackbishop in fact the problem was not in the trailing zero but the number is too big than an integer, like "0371327600000". Thanks

Comment: In this case I used to cast to `double`